# Disadvantage of using JS based navigation solution like React Navigation instead of using Native Navigation like Wix's React Native Navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, velo

The only reason I can think of using Native Navigation is when I have more screens & JS based solution like React Navigation will keep all the screens in memory. Now I am not a native developer so the above thing might be vague.

Comment: I agree with it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm one of the contributors of react-native-navigation. This question was a commonly asked, and I have written an answer before (as react-navigation VS react-native-navigation).

React-Navigation is Javascript-based navigation, that means all the navigate happen inside of single Activity (on Android and iOS counterpart).

The good part about Javascript based navigation is they will work on most platforms. But they usually suffer from performance issues due to stacks everything in the same activity.

React-Native-Navigation on another hand is actual native navigation. Every screen has its native container that handles native system. Better optimize better performance at the cost of deep integrate for each platform.

Hope this help.

Comment: What about Animations because React Navigation has some janky behaviour & some animations have weird behaviours like https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2539

Comment: I think people at Wix should write article where they compare JS vs Native routers. This way it can be always referred when this topic comes up (which is often)

Comment: @deadcoder0904 The issue you mention will be resolved by adjusting the native code animation (which is not hard). The performance issue of JS-based navigation is a complete different story.